# Entity Framework InvalidOperationException on Save

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, invalidoperationexception, navigation-properties

When I create a new EF object, I first attach it to the DbSet then set one of its Navigation Properties to a new instance of a different EF object. I then add the first EF to the DbSet and call save. I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The changes to the database were committed 
successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The 
ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A 
referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 
'Location.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) 
of 'Pool.LocationId' on the other end.
```

Here's my code:

```
ORMContext context = new ORMContext();

var l = context.Locations.Create();
context.Locations.Attach(l);
...set properties
context.Locations.Add(l);

var p = context.Pools.Create();
context.Pools.Attach(p);
p.Location = l;
...set properties
context.Pools.Add(p);

context.SaveChanges();
```

What I think is happening is the `Location` object is new and its `Id` is `0` by default. EF is updating the foreign key on `Pool` (which is set to `0`) and then `Location.Id` gets updated after the `Location` object is saved to the database. So `Location.Id` is now set to the associated value in the database, say `149`, and `Pool.LocationId` is still set to `0`.

How do I avoid this exception? Or how am I suppose to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

You can save after adding the location, that way the reference to the entity will be set

```
    ORMContext context = new ORMContext();

    var l = context.Locations.Create();
    context.Locations.Attach(l);
    ...set properties
    context.Locations.Add(l);

    context.SaveChanges(); // save here, that way the location will get its Id
    var p = context.Pools.Create();
    context.Pools.Attach(p);
    p.Location = l;
    ...set properties
    context.Pools.Add(p);

    context.SaveChanges();
```

That would be a way

Comment: Agreed. That would solve the problem. However, that's not an option. It would then save any other changes sitting in the DbContext which I can't force to happen until the user selects Save in the UI.